# SQL Query from multiple tables show all records

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please advise me on what I am doing wrong with query below

Scenario:

Data is in Three tables, One table contains complete record, other two tables have missing records, I want a query to based on Table A(where all records are present) and other two tables show result accordingly just like excel ( index match ) problem is it is filtering data correctly but shows only those records where all data matches in all three tables, I want query to show data even if it is available only in only one table.

Query I have generated so far:

```
SELECT primaryitemtable.itemcode, 
       primaryitemtable.itemdescription, 
       primaryitemtable.article, 
       itembatchlist.batchno, 
       Sum(tempscmstock.qty)    AS SumOfQty, 
       Sum(stockmastertemp.qty) AS SumOfQty1, 
       tempscmstock.batch, 
       stockmastertemp.batch 
FROM   (stockmastertemp 
        INNER JOIN (tempscmstock 
                    INNER JOIN primaryitemtable 
                            ON tempscmstock.itemcode = 
                   primaryitemtable.itemcode) 
                ON ( stockmastertemp.itemcode = primaryitemtable.itemcode ) 
                   AND ( stockmastertemp.itemcode = primaryitemtable.itemcode )) 
       INNER JOIN itembatchlist 
               ON primaryitemtable.itemcode = itembatchlist.itemcode 
GROUP  BY primaryitemtable.itemcode, 
          primaryitemtable.itemdescription, 
          primaryitemtable.article, 
          itembatchlist.batchno, 
          tempscmstock.batch, 
          stockmastertemp.batch 
HAVING ( ( ( tempscmstock.batch ) = [itembatchlist] ! [batchno] ) 
         AND ( ( stockmastertemp.batch ) = [itembatchlist] ! [batchno] ) ) 
ORDER  BY primaryitemtable.itemcode;
```

[[image]]

Comment: research `LEFT JOINS`

Comment: have tried, LEFT JOIN showing same result as in INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Try Left join because inner join return only those records where every table has same data

```
SELECT primaryitemtable.itemcode, 
       primaryitemtable.itemdescription, 
       primaryitemtable.article, 
       itembatchlist.batchno, 
       Sum(tempscmstock.qty)    AS SumOfQty, 
       Sum(stockmastertemp.qty) AS SumOfQty1, 
       tempscmstock.batch, 
       stockmastertemp.batch 
FROM   (stockmastertemp 
        LEFT JOIN (tempscmstock 
                   LEFT JOIN primaryitemtable 
                          ON tempscmstock.itemcode = primaryitemtable.itemcode) 
               ON ( stockmastertemp.itemcode = primaryitemtable.itemcode ) 
                  AND ( stockmastertemp.itemcode = primaryitemtable.itemcode )) 
       LEFT JOIN itembatchlist 
              ON primaryitemtable.itemcode = itembatchlist.itemcode 
GROUP  BY primaryitemtable.itemcode, 
          primaryitemtable.itemdescription, 
          primaryitemtable.article, 
          itembatchlist.batchno, 
          tempscmstock.batch, 
          stockmastertemp.batch 
HAVING ( ( ( tempscmstock.batch ) = [itembatchlist] ! [batchno] ) 
         AND ( ( stockmastertemp.batch ) = [itembatchlist] ! [batchno] ) ) 
ORDER  BY primaryitemtable.itemcode
```

Comment: left join works as like inner join if you have same number of join key in both tables

Comment: @fahadaleem can you share your source data cause you shared only output data it would be helpful to guide properly

Comment: Please find below the link of sample DB containing same data as of attached query along with tables

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HoyStIsTyxdhEPmFdb3oeEU84mMaIDhy